# SR0007 : Microsoft.Rules.Data : Nullable columns can cause final results to be evaluated as NULL for the predicate

Tags: sql-server

There's a query in my sp like:

```
DELETE
    FROM MySchema.TableA
    WHERE Attr1 = @Var1 AND Attr2 = @Var2
```

But when building it using vs2019, an error raises:

```
Error:  : SR0007 : Microsoft.Rules.Data : Nullable columns can cause final results to be evaluated as NULL for the predicate.
```

I tried to change the query to(it fixes the same error of other queries):

```
DELETE
    FROM MySchema.TableA
    WHERE Attr1 = ISNULL(@Var1, '') AND Attr2 = ISNULL(@Var2, '')
```

However, it doesn't work. My question is, how do I remove this error? Thank you!

Comment: That "error" seems like poor advice. Comparing to `NULL` values is a frequent and common scenario, and isn't an "error" at all.

Comment: @Larnu But it appears as an error:( Do u know why the "error" still exists after I apply ```ISNULL()```?

Comment: When it comes up, right click on it and turn off the code analysis rule associated with it. You can safely ignore this one. The warning is probably appearing because `Attr1` in `TableA` is a nullable column.

Comment: @allmhuran they are not nullable column however... Both Attr1 and Attr2 are set to ```NOT NULL``` in table definition.

Comment: Oh well, it doesn't really matter either way, you can dismiss that check anyway.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the `SR0007` rule in SSDT. The only real option is to suppress it on a per-procedure basis.

Comment: @Dai thats right